# Should the threshold of an "expensive" operation change with infrastructure?

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, memcached

I'm using [Amazon ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) for session storage and expensive operation caching on a multi-node web application. One gotchya – I failed to take into account the network latency of the ElastiCache node(s) compared to a local Memcached server.

My benchmarks are show 1-2ms response times for ElastiCache calls within an AWS VPC (as advertised), pretty good, but obviously dramatically slower than anything local. In terms of actual compute cycles 1-2ms is a lifetime. This dramatically changes what I can consider an "expensive" operation worth caching.

My inexperience that led me down this path, but I would imagine others must have similar issues when moving into the "cloud".

**Question:** Is it better to rethink (and rewrite) what qualifies as an "expensive" operation, or should the infrastructure do a better job of supporting the code (for example, I could use a local memcached server on each node and only pass cache misses through to the ElastiCache node).

Comment: How many calls to ElasticCache are you making on average to serve one request ? Also, according to me, 1-2ms is like nothing, and you should not worry because of that ideally.

Comment: probably 15-20 elasticache calls on average. which can add up to around 50ms (my target time is 150ms total). It doesn't make sense to "cache" something that takes .5ms to generate if its going to take 1-2ms to pull it out of cache. But typically I would consider a .5ms operation (for example, a recursive directory scan) a pretty expensive operation worthy of caching. So this throws that for a bit of a loop, and my question is: what should change, the code or the infrastructure. What do other people do?

Comment: added an answer, with few open questions, we can discuss that, and can find best solution.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some open questions:

- How did you benchmarked ? 
   1-2ms was from connection opening to close, or just fetching time.
- Why you need 15-20 average calls, can they be reduced ? 
  If yes, that might be better.
- Is Amazon ElasticCache on same region as your servers ?

Now coming to solutions (will update according to above questions' answer):

**Possible Solution**
Divide things which you are fine displaying stale values, and things which should be non-staled and common across all servers (example money in wallet, etc.). Now setup two layer caching, one layer i.e. on server only, and save all values which can be staled individually on different servers, and maintain common AmazonElastic cache for stable values. This can be one of working strategy.

Comment: - Benchmark a series of `memcached_get` operations, averaged out over time.
- The 15-20 calls is the question. Like my comment above, it makes a lot of sense to do this with a local memcached install because it can really shave off compute time and cycles. But in the cloud environment that calculus changes.
- Yes, same region, az, and vpc.

Comment: I think the solution is to (as you suggest and I mentioned in the original post) have 2 layers of caching. One local install on each server, and then a "master" living in the "remote" elasticache node(s). The remote node would hold a global key to namespace all the local calls. This would allow you to "clear cache" on all remote and local nodes simultaneously by just changing the cache key. Local cache misses would pass through to the elasticache node and then also store that value locally – something like that anyway. Is two layer caching commonplace?